# How to fix Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter

Tags: java

I seen some threads about it but it didn't really helped me...

I have java JDK 10. Running on Windows 10 64-bit. The thing I'm trying to use is a bot. The github link about it is [here](https://github.com/OlympicCode/vHackOSBot-Java).

Here's the logs of the script I'm executing

```
C:\Users\administrator\Downloads\vHackOSBot>java -jar vHackOSBot.jar
20:15:09 INFO [UpdateService] Creating UpdateService...
20:15:09 INFO [MiscService] Creating MiscService...
20:15:09 INFO [NetworkingService] Creating NetworkingService...
20:15:09 INFO [MainService] Creating MainService...
20:15:09 INFO [ServerService] Creating ServerService...
20:15:09 INFO [vHackOSBot-Config] Creating ConfigFile...
20:15:09 INFO [vHackOSBot-ConfigAdv] Creating ConfigFile...
20:15:09 WARN [io.sentry.DefaultSentryClientFactory] No 'stacktrace.app.packages' was configured, this option is highly recommended as it affects stacktrace grouping and display on Sentry. See documentation: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/#in-application-stack-frames
20:15:09 WARN [io.sentry.DefaultSentryClientFactory] No 'stacktrace.app.packages' was configured, this option is highly recommended as it affects stacktrace grouping and display on Sentry. See documentation: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/#in-application-stack-frames
20:15:10 INFO [vHackOSBot-ConfigAdv] Loading advanced config...
20:15:10 INFO [vHackOSBot-ConfigAdv] Loaded advanced config in 223ms.
20:15:10 INFO [vHackOSBot-ConfigAdv] Saving advanced config...
20:15:10 INFO [vHackOSBot-ConfigAdv] Saved advanced config in 29ms.
20:15:10 INFO [vHackOSBot-Config] Loading config...
20:15:10 INFO [vHackOSBot-Config] Loaded config in 47ms.
20:15:10 INFO [vHackOSBot-Config] Saving config...
20:15:10 INFO [vHackOSBot-Config] Saved config in 2ms.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
        at net.olympiccode.vhackos.api.utils.Encryption.md5Hash(Encryption.java:15)
        at net.olympiccode.vhackos.api.requests.Route.compile(Route.java:59)
        at net.olympiccode.vhackos.api.entities.impl.vHackOSAPIImpl.verifyDetails(vHackOSAPIImpl.java:108)
        at net.olympiccode.vhackos.api.entities.impl.vHackOSAPIImpl.login(vHackOSAPIImpl.java:83)
        at net.olympiccode.vhackos.api.vHackOSAPIBuilder.buildAsync(vHackOSAPIBuilder.java:92)
        at net.olympiccode.vhackos.api.vHackOSAPIBuilder.buildBlocking(vHackOSAPIBuilder.java:104)
        at net.olympiccode.vhackos.bot.core.vHackOSBot.run(vHackOSBot.java:107)
        at net.olympiccode.vhackos.bot.core.vHackOSBot.main(vHackOSBot.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more
20:15:10 INFO [vHackOSBot] Shutting down...
20:15:10 INFO [vHackOSBot-Config] Saving config...
20:15:10 INFO [vHackOSBot-Config] Saved config in 2ms.
20:15:10 INFO [vHackOSBot-ConfigAdv] Saving advanced config...
20:15:10 INFO [vHackOSBot-ConfigAdv] Saved advanced config in 1ms.
```

Comment: Looks like the implementation of `javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter` is not on your Classpath

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75691813/12349305 it work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found why it wasn't working. I needed to downgrade to java jde and jdk 8

Comment: while that is a possible solution it will bind you to that java version. I highly recommend following @sagat approach.

Answer (score 11):

With JDK 9 java.xml.bind is dprecated and removed from standard classpath.
Its still there so you could try a workaround and use **--add-modules** to add Modules to your classpath.

But for me the easiest solution was adding the dependency (gradle/maven):

**gradle:**

```
compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'
```

**maven:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

link to deprecation summary: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.xml.bind-summary.html